# El Capitan + Microsoft Office 2016 + Category Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, macos, ms-office, shortcut

I am trying to add shortcut for Microsoft Outlook categories. I have found [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110133/172520) for Office 2011 but it doesn't work with Office 2016 on El Capitan. Does anyone know how to assign this shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Outlook-2013-and-2016-3e1090f6-a616-42db-abf5-269ca3d553ee) may be what you are looking for:

It only references deleting color categories, which is ALT + D.

Comment: These are for Windows (Mac veresion [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-07ae68c8-b7af-4010-b225-324c04ac7335)). Anyway, it is not useful for me - I'd like to assign my own shortcut to be able for example assign "Green Category" to an e-mail by shortcut CTRL+Alt+G.